# Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.62 (1.7.2) XML Configuration Files best practices

Tags: xml, tomcat, jdbc, configuration, jndi

I have unzipped a binary distribution in `C://` but I have a hard time getting the `JDBC` and `JDNI` working... It does not get the data from my database so I assume I do not have the proper configuration for the files.

> Strangely, i'm able to see data with `<c:forEach var="cartItem" items="${cart.items}" varStatus="iter"/>`but no data displays with `<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter"/>`

**EDIT**

server.xml: /conf

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- TomEE plugin for Tomcat -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               redirectPort="8443"/>
    
    
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

context.xml: /META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/Application">
  <!-- maxActive: Maximum number of database connections in pool. Make sure you
         configure your mysqld max_connections large enough to handle
         all of your db connections. Set to -1 for no limit.
         -->
  <!-- maxIdle: Maximum number of idle database connections to retain in pool.
         Set to -1 for no limit.  See also the DBCP documentation on this
         and the minEvictableIdleTimeMillis configuration parameter.
         -->
  <!-- maxWait: Maximum time to wait for a database connection to become available
         in ms, in this example 10 seconds. An Exception is thrown if
         this timeout is exceeded.  Set to -1 to wait indefinitely.
         -->
  <!-- username and password: MySQL username and password for database connections  -->
  <!-- driverClassName: Class name for the old mm.mysql JDBC driver is
         org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - we recommend using Connector/J though.
         Class name for the official MySQL Connector/J driver is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
         -->
  <!-- url: The JDBC connection url for connecting to your MySQL database.
         -->
  <resources>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/application" object-type="user" pool-name="ApplicationPool">
      <description/>
    </jdbc-resource>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" 
                          associate-with-thread="false" 
                          connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
                          connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
                          connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
                          connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
                          connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
                          datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" 
                          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
                          fail-all-connections="false" 
                          idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
                          is-connection-validation-required="false" 
                          is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
                          lazy-connection-association="false" 
                          lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
                          match-connections="false" 
                          max-connection-usage-count="0" 
                          max-pool-size="32" 
                          max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
                          name="ApplicationPool" 
                          non-transactional-connections="false" 
                          pool-resize-quantity="2" 
                          res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" 
                          statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
                          steady-pool-size="8" 
                          validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
                          wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
      <description>Connects to the database</description>
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/application?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="User" value="root"/>
      <property name="Password" value="password"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
  </resources>
</Context>
```

### 2nd EDIT

I added these jars in $CATALINA_HOME/lib:

- javaee-api-6.0-6.jar
- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar

No WAR file was exploded since as for right now i'm developing locally in Netbeans 8.0.2 but if it's the same thing as deployment the server automatically  created a copy under `Web Applications`(pardon my ignorance if it's the same).

The log of today:

```
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/resources/jdbc-resource/description'.
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/resources/jdbc-resource'.
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/resources/jdbc-connection-pool/description'.
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/resources/jdbc-connection-pool/property'.
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/resources/jdbc-connection-pool/property'.
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/resources/jdbc-connection-pool/property'.
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/resources/jdbc-connection-pool'.
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/resources'.
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:15 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: C:\Users\PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Mebzone\build\web
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.PagerTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.ParamTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.ItemTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.IndexTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.FirstTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.PrevTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.PageTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.PagesTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.NextTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.LastTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.SkipTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.PagerTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.ParamTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.ItemTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.IndexTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.FirstTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.PrevTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.PageTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.PagesTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.NextTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.LastTag
Jun 23, 2015 8:10:17 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans deploy
SEVERE: Unable to load tag library tag class: com.jsptags.navigation.pager.SkipTag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resource.xml is not an Apache Tomcat configurstion file. persistence.xml is not an Apache Tomcat configuration file.

server.xml must be located in the conf directory.

You have a few more options for context.xml but I'd recommend the META-INF directory of your web application.

If you want help with your configuration then you'll need to provide more information including:

- full Tomcat version
- configuration files you've added/edited
- where you placed your WAR file / exploded directory
- any additional JARs you added and where you placed them
- any error messages in the logs

**Update after the above information was provided**

The configuration for the DataSource is wrong. Tomcat does not support the <jdbc-resource /> nor the <jdbc-connection-pool /> tags. If support for those is provided by TomEE then I can't help you (I only know Tomcat). In Tomcat, I'd expect to see a <Resource ... /> element.

For Tomcat (and I suspect TomEE), you'll need to provide the MySQL JDBC driver JAR in $CATALINA_BASE/lib.

Comment: This tutorial https://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/jndi-settings-toplink-glassfish-tomcat  seems to think `persistence.xml` must be configured just like any other files for Tomcat to work. As for `resources.xml` I never saw that file before when using Glassfish. It was automatically created when I created `JDBC` resources for TomEE. I will edit my answer with the content of every XML file listed above.

Comment: And the rest of the information you were asked to provide?

Comment: I edited my answer. It's weird the log says `WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/resources/jdbc-connection-pool/property'.` I tested the connection with below code:

Comment: `<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% Connection connection = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/<DATABASE NAME>?user=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>");
Statement sql = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = sql.executeQuery("SELECT product FROM category_has_product");
while(result.next() )
{
out.println(result.getString("product_id") + "<br />");
} %>`

Comment: And I was able to display all the product IDs which is a good sign that Tomcat can successfully connect to the DB and retrieve requested data